# Trying to get a desired output from a text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a output like this in a text file, where `^M` represents CR

```
Last login: Sat Jan 22 09:49:50 2023 from 10.1.1.1^M

Cisco Router

uptime
exit -f
Connecting user mike from 10.1.1.1
****************************************** Warning ******************************************^M
^M
Warning monitoring.^M
^M
*********************************************************************************************^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv1.nue99.de> uptime^M
^[[1A^[[2K^[[1A^[[2Kmike@grv1.nue99.de> uptime^M
9 days,  3:43^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv1.nue99.de> exit -f^M
Shutting down the session^M
^M
Connection closed
Last login: Sat Jan 21 09:49:49 2023 from  10.1.1.1^M
Cisco Router

uptime
exit -f
Connecting user mike from  10.1.1.1
****************************************** Warning ******************************************^M
^M
Warning monitoring.^M^M
^M
*********************************************************************************************^M
^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv2.nue99.de> uptime^M
^[[1A^[[2K^[[1A^[[2Kmike@grv2.nue99.de> uptime^M
10 days,  3:43^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv2.nue99.de> exit -f^M
Shutting down the session^M
^M
Connection closed
Last login: Sat Jan 21 09:49:49 2023 from  10.1.1.1^M

Cisco Router

uptime
exit -f
Connecting user mike from  10.1.1.1
****************************************** Warning ******************************************^M
^M

^M
*********************************************************************************************^M
^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv1.nue98.de> uptime^M
^[[1A^[[2K^[[1A^[[2Kmike@grv1.nue98.de> uptime^M
11 days,  3:43^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv1.nue98.de> exit -f^M
Shutting down the session^M
^M
Connection closed
Last login: Sat Jan 21 09:49:49 2023 from  10.1.1.1^M

Cisco Router

uptime
exit -f
Connecting user mike from  10.1.1.1
****************************************** Warning ******************************************^M
^M

^M
*********************************************************************************************^M
^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv2.nue98.de> uptime^M
^[[1A^[[2K^[[1A^[[2Kmike@grv2.nue98.de> uptime^M
12 days,  3:43^M
[ ne ]^M
mike@grv2.nue99.de> exit -f^M
Shutting down the session^M
^M
Connection closed

^M
```

I am trying to achieve a output something like this

```
grv1.nue99.de> uptime  9 days, 3:43
grv2.nue99.de> uptime 10 days, 3:43
grv1.nue98.de> uptime 11 days, 3:43
grv2.nue98.de> uptime 12 days, 3:43
```

I have tried

```
awk '/mike@.*> uptime/ {print;getline;print}' testbeta1.text > testbeta2.txt 
sed 's/mike@//g; s/> uptime/> uptime /g' test.txt > test1.txt 
grep -oP 'mike@.*uptime.*\K[0-9]+\sdays.*' testbeta.text
```

Can someone help me to reach the desired output

Comment: @roaima those are cr

Comment: is the uptime value always have the string "days" associated with it? Please fix the uptime in the example so the values in the output match the values in the input - currently you have values like `8 days` in the output which don't exist in the input as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi Ed i fixed it.

Comment: and is "days" ALWAYS present in your real uptime values?

Comment: no days is not always present

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that you should be using [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) for - it's what network monitoring tools like nagios, icinga, mrtg, and many others use.  You can query the uptime (and many other values) without needing to parse the output of a telnet session.   Alternatively use an [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/) script (or [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) for python / [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/Expect) for perl).

Comment: @rmb if `days` isn't always present then [edit] your example to include such a case. You accepted one of the answers that assumes `days` is always present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
cat testbeta1.text | tr -d "\r" | tr "\n" " " | tr -s " " | grep -Eo 'mike@[^>]+> uptime [0-9]+ days, [0-9]+:[0-9]+' | cut -d "@" -f 2-
```

Explanations:

- `tr -d "\r"`: remove all CR characters
- `tr "\n" " "`: replace each LF character by one space
- `tr -s " "`: replace each sequence of a repeated space by only one space
- `grep -Eo 'mike@[^>]+> uptime [0-9]+ days, [0-9]+:[0-9]+'`: get all sequences (`-E`) who accept the regex and only them (`-o`)
- `cut -d "@" -f 2-`: get the part of line after the first '`@`' character

With your example:

```bash
> cat testbeta1.text | tr -d "\r" | tr "\n" " " | tr -s " " | grep -Eo 'mike@[^>]+> uptime [0-9]+ days, [0-9]+:[0-9]+' | cut -d "@" -f 2-
grv1.nue99.de> uptime 9 days, 3:43
grv2.nue99.de> uptime 10 days, 3:43
grv1.nue98.de> uptime 11 days, 3:43
grv2.nue98.de> uptime 12 days, 3:43
```

Comment: I get no output at all

Comment: Arnaud, the `^M` is a representation for CR, not the two literal characters. You'll need to replace your `sed` with `tr -d '\r'`. Or better, strip it entirely and change the next part to `tr '\r\n' '  '`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed for remove all CR characters

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution. I've used `tr` to strip the CR characters from each line. The whole thing (except for the `#` comments) can be crashed into a relatively unreadable single line but I've presented it across several lines here to help improve readability:

```
tr -d '\r' <script |
awk -F'[@ ]' '
    # If we have a hostname set, print it and the uptime value; reset for next time
    host && /:/ {printf "%s uptime %s\n", host, $0; host=""}

    # Capture hostname if input matches ">" from the prompt and keyword "uptime"
    !host && />/ && /uptime/ {host=$2}
'
```

Output from the example

```
grv1.nue99.de> uptime 9 days,  3:43
grv2.nue99.de> uptime 10 days,  3:43
grv1.nue98.de> uptime 11 days,  3:43
grv2.nue98.de> uptime 12 days,  3:43
```

Comment: Thanks Roaima Your solution worked